# Which files should be include/ignore for modelio

Tags: git, modelio

I am using modelio 3.3.1 with the following details:

> Windows 7 64bit
>     Modelio: Version 3.3.1
>     Build: 201502191121
>     Metamodel: 9023
>     System: win32 (6.1)
>     Architecture: x86_64

I want to use git 1.9.0 to keep every version.
The tree in project directory is huge.
Should I keep them all?
Or Which files/directories should I put int .gitignore?

Many thanks.

Regards,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

First try to update your git to version 2+ if you can since there are some major differences.
Second try to add any files/folders that you don't want to track in your `.gitignore` file.

#### What to put?

Its your call what you want and need to track and what you don't need.